# Can two representations with different dimensions be isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

For a finite group G and two irreducible representations, with different dimensions. How would I show that they can not be isomorphic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An isomorphism of representations is in particular an isomorphism of vector spaces. Two vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

Comment: Really? two vector spaces having the same dimension is equivalent to them being isomorphic?

Comment: @john Yes (provided of course they are over the same field). It doesn't mean they're isomorphic as representations though.